# How do I set an alias that works only from a particular folder in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm using powershell to manage the building of some .net projects on my machine, and I'd like to create aliases for them. The only trick is that I'd like to only use the aliases when I'm in the folder containing all the code. Is there a way to apply aliases only in a particular folder?

Comment: That is not how aliases work.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers is correct! Other option is create some .bat files inside that folders.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it due to its obscurity, but you could **dynamically add and remove aliases or functions via the `prompt` function** that determines the interactive prompt string, because it is called after every command.

Note that PowerShell aliases only allow aliasing command *names* (or paths); that is, you can't bake arguments into them, which is why the following example uses a *function* instead (but it would work analogously for aliases):

```
function prompt {
  # Define function `gs` on demand whenever the current location is a in a Git
  # repo folder, and remove it when switching to any other folder.
  if (Test-Path ./.git) { function global:gs { git status $Args } }
                   else { Remove-Item -EA Ignore function:global:gs }
  # Define the standard PS prompt string.
  "PS $PWD$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) "
}
```

To lessen the obscurity, you could modify the prompt string to signal whether or not the folder-specific commands are in effect:

```
function prompt {
  # Define function `gs` on demand whenever the current location is a in a Git
  # repo folder, and remove it when switching to any other folder.
  if (Test-Path ./.git) {
    $indicator = '[repo]'
    function global:gs { git status $Args }
  } else {
    $indicator = ''
    Remove-Item -EA Ignore function:global:gs
  }

  # Define the standard PS prompt string.
  "PS $PWD $indicator$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) "
}
```

Now your prompt will contain substring `[repo]` (e.g., `PS /Users/jdoe/Projects/foo [repo]>`) whenever the current location is a Git repo folder.